# Maximum value of datetime field

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

Is it possible to show the Maximum of date time value in Powerbi as you can do for integer fields?

I want to see in a tile last time an event received and the value for that sensor event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You will create a Measure in your data model like:
MaxDate:= MAX(Table[Datecolumn])

then you'll have a table with a single row, let's call it:
DescriptiveStatistics

You can add this using Power Query if you'd like. 
In Power Pivot you'll add a calculated column named "Max Date" with expression:
=MaxDate

Then you'll use the DescriptiveStatistics[Max Date] column in your Power View.

HTH,
-Lukasz

http://dev.powerbi.com

http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the fact that I am sending data from Stream Analytics and cannot do all these staff.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a totally different question.  Could you mark my answer as answering the question you asked? For the SA use case, it's not yet supported.